# How to embed RecordDetail lightning component into our own custom component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, page-layout, record

I'm trying to get below lightning component into a own custom component.

[image]

Seems not exposed to embed, just tried below and no luck.

```
<c:recordDetail recordId="{!v.contactId}"/>
```

> No COMPONENT named markup://c:recordDetail found :

Any help on achieving this, so that it will show up default layout set up for the profile of current user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce does provide this via **[force:recordView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordView.htm)**

A force:recordView component represents a read-only view of a record. You can display the record view using different layout types. By default, the record view uses the full layout to display all fields of the record. The mini layout displays fields corresponding to the compact layout. You can change the fields and the order they appear in the component by going to Compact Layouts in Setup for the particular object.

```
<force:recordView recordId="{!v.contactid}" type="FULL"/>
```

You can provide a dynamic ID for the recordId attribute using the format {!v.myObject.recordId}

Limitation: This is read only layout.

Answer (score 0):

The available components alongside their code/documentation etc etc can be found at

yourSalesforceInstance.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app

the components are referenced under their namespace, and have usage examples, and so on.

When you do create your new component, make sure you scope to the appropriate interface. for example:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
```

Comment: Thanks @glls, but it does not expose components available in Standard Designer it seems, would be great to have it in [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Tr96QAC) for it.

Comment: either you didn't go through the list of components, or for some reason are unsure how to use them...the aura docs for your org should be quite clear

Comment: yes, have gone through already. I agree with you. they are helpful. thanks for helping on it.